# We need 'Code-only answer' category in the Low Quality Answers review

Tags: feature-request, code-only-answers, low-quality-answers

My understanding is that a code-only answer is not recommended in this community.

When I reviewed the 'Low Quality Answers', I wanted to choose 'Code-only' answer but there was no such category.

Should we create a new category for the review?

Comment: What would be the action linked to this choice? Code-only answers are not recommended, but not disallowed either.

Answer (score 18):

No, we don't need a code-only answer category.

In the Low Quality Answer queue we want to get rid of any answers that are utter garbage and can't by any means be turned into a viable contribution that is worth keeping. Handling review items should be done with the mindset: *delete this answer, yes or no?*

A code-only answer shouldn't be deleted when it answers a question, specially the question. Code-only answers are down-vote material, not delete-vote material. After all a code-only answer can be improved with an edit. We need our delete-votes for the truly horrible non-salvageable content and therefore there shouldn't be a code-only answer category in the low quality answer review queue.

Comment: "After all a code-only answer can be improved with an edit"... but I [don't see especially strong consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163) that we may actually do so. Let's be realistic here; people who dump code-only answers onto the site can quite rarely be even successfully communicated with, let alone convinced to edit in an explanation. And we know voting doesn't work, largely because almost all of it is done by people with approximately the same level of skill as the question's OP (not counting artificial canonicals).

Comment: "We need our delete-votes for the truly horrible non-salvageable content" - how many users out there are regularly at risk of running out of delete votes for the day? Do you realize how rare it is to stumble upon answers with outstanding delete votes in the wild? Significant coordination problem, there.

Comment: I will upvote this because it is technically correct, but I also support what Karl and Ryan say. There remains a gap between what is intended and how it will be used today and how it will be used today will not be the product of deep attention to detail, it will be the product of assumption making. And boy does the site make it easy to make the wrong assumptions. So I definitely won't downvote the meta post either, I just have a little trouble with the fact that it states we need it. No we *may* need it. Discussion, not a feature request. Not yet.

Answer (score 9):

#### Yes (but without recommending deletion)

**...because people won't say that a *bad* answer "Looks OK"**

Code-only answers shouldn't be deleted if they attempt to answer the question.  The correct response to these is "Looks OK", maybe with a comment *encouraging* the poster to explain the answer in an edit if it's not clear (sometimes people add detail if encouraged!).

But we have long had an epidemic of misguided people in Low Quality Answers review recommending deletion of various types of "bad" answers, including code-only or otherwise unexplained answers.  It's hard to blame them: the queue is called "Low Quality Answers", and these are often pretty low quality, and certainly saying it "looks OK" seems like a stretch.

I'd call the option "Needs more explanation", and it could perhaps leave a comment, but critically, it would *not* recommend deletion.  Its primary purpose would be to guide reviewers into doing the right thing; even just having a second option that does the same thing as "Looks OK" would be helpful in this regard.